# Algebraic Closure and Ordered Fields

Tags: field-theory

Let $F$ be a field and denote by $K$ its algebraic closure. Is it true that if $[K:F]=2$ then $F$ is ordered? Such fields are real-closed fields, but what about being ordered?

We can see it is true for $\mathbb{R}$ and its algebraic closure $\mathbb{C}$, but what about other such fields?

Comment: [Here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/artinschreier.pdf) KCd proves that $K=F(i)$ which is an important step to show that $a\ge b\iff \sqrt{a-b}\in F$ is an order.